# The comma, the full stop, but an asterisk, and an ellipsis?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

For what reason Wikipedia lists [comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) as *the* comma, [full stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) as *the* full stop, [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) as *the* ampersand, but [asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) as **an** asterisk, and [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) as **an** ellipsis?

For what reason Wikipedia use different articles for them? Does it mean that it is assumed that the last two are probably unknown to an average reader?

Comment: [Why does x = the form for a question in English.]

Comment: @Lambie Slightly edited.

Comment: **Why does Wikipedia list etc.** **Not** *for what reason Wikipedia lists*.  That is not grammatical in English and is not a question form.

Comment: This isn't strictly a question of English, but of Wikipedia's conventions, and it probably comes down to the fact that different people authored the line in different articles. In my own writing, I would prefer *the* in all cases here as indicating an archetype.

Comment: I don't know how we can tell you why Wikipedia does the things that it does.

Comment: @Lambie *For what reason does Wikipedia* would be grammatical, if unnecessarily wordy.

Comment: But ['the pilcrow'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow). It looks to be mere inconsistency.

Comment: There are apparently [***a couple of hundred***](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki+%22the+asterisk+is%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki+%22the+asterisk+is%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60l2.1046943j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) written instances of ***the** asterisk is [whatever it is]* on the Wikipedia site. And I bet not one of them has *[whatever it is] = **not very well known*** or similar.

Comment: *Ellipsis* only gained an article in [February 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ellipsis&diff=prev&oldid=764058491), whereas *asterisk* has started as *an asterisk* [since the creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Asterisk&oldid=103925). Tell you what, I'm going to make the question moot.

Comment: @choster Many things are grammatical. First one learns the basics, doesn't one? Why does x, in that sense, comes before, For what reason does...but it's all good.

Comment: Every single one of those entries begins with the. The horse is a noble animal. A horse can be a wonderful companion. See? In English, we move from *the* (refers to a category) to a (refers to a thing in general).

Comment: Remember, Wikipedia is written not by elite professionals, but by volunteers, often "amateurs".  Few people are going to complain about the choice of an article so long as the entire, um, article is largely correct.

Comment: @HotLicks *elite* professionals? One thing is to bring order out of chaos (edit the Wikipedia texts), another is to not know how chaos works. Wikipedia is chaotic but languages have their logic....

Comment: @Lambie - XD  :))  :'D  =^D  :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no reason for it. It makes very little difference whether an article begins with "the comma" or "a comma"; they mean the same thing and there's not much reason to choose one over the other.

In particular, the use of "a" instead of "the" does *not* indicate that asterisks or ellipses are probably unknown to an average reader.

The only difference—and it's a very small difference—is that if the article starts with "the comma", it's talking about the *type* of punctuation mark which is called "comma", and if it starts with "a comma", it's talking about *individual* punctuation marks that are commas. But this makes no difference at all.

By the way, after this question was posted, the Stack Exchange user [choster](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16052/choster) wrote in a comment:

> *Ellipsis* only gained an article in February 2017, whereas *asterisk* has started as *an asterisk* since the creation. Tell you what, I'm going to make the question moot.

choster then edited the Wikipedia articles "asterisk" and "ellipses" so that now, all five articles start with "the".

Comment: The OP's question is misguided. Have you clicked on every link? The first entry is always with a the determiner.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I clicked on all five Wikipedia links. The question correctly describes the articles as they were at the time the article was posted (three *the*, two *an*). As I mention in this answer, the articles were edited after this question was posted, so now all five say *the*.

Comment: @Lambie I clicked on every one almost an hour ago, when OP's question was logical if off-topic. The first entry may _now_ always start with a definite article. In another half hour, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

[...] Wikipedia lists comma as the comma, full stop as the full stop, ampersand as the ampersand, but asterisk as an asterisk, and ellipsis as an ellipsis?

Regardless of the properly edited or not properly edited text on Wikipedia, the point is the following:

Any noun discussed as a category in English can begin with **the**. It is used in formal sentences or explanations, usually in writing and not in speech.

- The horse is a noble animal.
- The apple is good for your health.

Used in this manner, the *the* refers to a type or category.

- Semantically, The horse is a noble animal. = Horses are noble animals.

So, "The comma" as used in Wikipedia is a formal way of saying: Commas etc.

In speech, we are apt to **say**: Commas are x and not The comma is x.

MIT instructions to students:

> **You can also use the definite article with a singular countable noun
>   to refer to the entire class that the noun belongs to. This is often
>   done with species of animals, inventions, or musical instruments**:
>
> **The honey possum of Australia is the only mammal that lives
>   exclusively on  nectar**.
>   --"Take It or Leave It," Valley Comic News

If making categorical formal statements, one can begin with the and move to a. OR one can begin with the plural noun.

- The comma is an interesting punctuation mark.
- Commas are interesting punctuation marks.

If you use a comma as the subject, you won't be making a generic statement about commas.

- A comma may or may not be used after certain phrases.

BUT NOT:
A comma is an interesting punctuation mark.

[MIT and use of the definite article the](http://www.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/art-appr.htm)

Comment: **Wikipedia does not do that. All those entries begin with "the".** Yes, but these changes were made by Choser. Here are the links to the original versions: [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Asterisk&oldid=959821649); [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ellipsis&oldid=959411022). As you see, they start with the _an_. Or maybe I don't have the correct understanding of what you said?

Comment: @jsv I am going by what I clicked on. By the time I got there, they were all "the" but this does not change my answer and my fundamental point, does it?

Comment: Fundamental point is still here :) And special "thanks" for MIT style guide. I think I could find many useful things in it.

Comment: @jsv OK, I edited my answer. Yes, the MIT guide is very good.